# Python: Calculate distance between two data points in Dictionary

Tags: python-2.7, dictionary, euclidean-distance

I have many data points in a dictionary list that is saved as:

{'Canada': ['10.625', '80.743'], 'Sao Tome and Principe': ['32.399', '63.935']}

I need to calculate the Euclidean distance between them by using the two numbers in each data point by using the formula:

```
sqrt{[x_j-x_i]**2 + [y_j-y_i]**2}
```

How can I so this with dictionaries? I can't figure out or find any answers on how to use the  [     ] part of the  {'Canada': ['10.625', '80.743']}

I need to write a function that calculates the distance between two data point coordinates in a dictionary, but I don't know where to begin.

```
def distance():
   # compute distance where two data point in a dictionary is used
   # data points e.g.: {'Canada': ['10.625', '80.743'], 'Sao Tome and Principe': ['32.399', '63.935']}
   distance = result(sqrt{[10.625,32.399]**2 + [80.743,63.935]**2})
```

Answer (score 1):

I think you would like to calculate the distance between all deo point is your dictionary right?
Than you have to create the cartesian product of the dictionary element by pairing them up into pairs. The itertools.product do it for you. Something like this:
from itertools import *

```
loc = {"c1": ["lat1","lon2"], "c2": ["lat2","lon2"], "c3": ["lat3","lon3"], }
print list(product(loc, repeat=2))
```

Output:

```
[('c3', 'c3'), ('c3', 'c2'), ('c3', 'c1'), ('c2', 'c3'), ('c2', 'c2'), ('c2', 'c1'), ('c1', 'c3'), ('c1', 'c2'), ('c1', 'c1')]
```

Than you have to iterate through the pairs and calculate their eucledian distance like this:

```
def distance(loc1, loc2):
    return ((loc1[0] - loc2[0])**(2) + (loc1[1] - loc2[1])**(2))**(.5)
```

If you multiply the distance value with the `magic_number = 111111` you'll get a relative good estime in kilometer for close coordinates.

But I thin you have to use the [harvesine distance](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/haversine) that's a more expensive formula but gives you the accurate distance (especially if you measure the distance between countries).

Answer (score 0):

For calculating the Euclidean distance between two data points you can use the following script using `numpy`

```
import NumPy as np
def euclidean_dis(row):
    return np.sqrt(np.sum((row['v'] - row['u']) ** 2))
```

And apply on your data frame, assuming you wanna calculate the Euclidean distance between column `v` and column `u`.

```
df["euclidean_distance"]=df.apply(euclidean_dis,axis=1)
```